# Using purrr::map and sjPlot::tab_model to generate many tables instead of one wide table

Tags: r, dictionary, sjplot

I want to run many models using `purrr::map()` and generate multiple single tables using `sjPlot::tab_model()`.

For example, using this toydata:

```
testdata <- structure(list(subject = c("B001", "B001", "B001", "B001", "B001", 
"B002", "B002", "B002", "B002", "B002", "B003", "B003", "B003", 
"B003", "B003", "B004", "B004", "B004", "B004", "B004", "B005", 
"B005", "B005", "B005", "B005"), time_point = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("Wk0", "Wk4", "Wk8", 
"Wk12", "Wk16"), class = "factor"), sfa = c(62.895, 84.705, 83.49, 
66.64, 72.19, 56.195, 93.945, 92.635, 88.51, 83.505, 92.67, 90.81, 
83.37, 90.205, 84.195, 88.065, 53.69, 93.14, 52.57, 95.995, 63.505, 
92.59, 80.87, 89.125, 67.305), mufa = c(14.455, 11.71, 12.58, 
21.135, 26.175, 13.285, 4.91, 6.08, 6.735, 12.745, 7.325, 7.605, 
15.735, 7.985, 12.32, 7.92, 42.045, 4.57, 24.305, 4.505, 18.585, 
5.955, 14.815, 8.775, 20.295), pufa = c(22.65, 3.58, 3.935, 12.23, 
1.635, 30.525, 1.135, 1.275, 4.76, 3.75, 0, 1.595, 0.885, 1.82, 
3.495, 4.01, 4.26, 2.29, 23.125, 0, 17.905, 1.455, 4.305, 2.1, 
12.4)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I can run 3 models

```
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
library(broom.mixed)

modsfa <- lmer(sfa ~ time_point + (1| subject), 
             data = testdata)
modmufa <- lmer(mufa ~ time_point + (1| subject), 
               data = testdata)
modpufa <- lmer(pufa ~ time_point + (1| subject), 
               data = testdata)
```

And then generate three tables (as I wanted)

```
tab_model(modsfa)
tab_model(modmufa)
tab_model(modpufa)
```

I know I can use

```
tab_model(modsfa, modmufa, modpufa)
```

But I do not want that table (because the table will be really wide).

So, I thought I could use `purrr::map()` and generate 3 tables as above

```
testdata |> 
  select(sfa:pufa) |>
  map(~ lmer(.x ~ time_point + (1| subject), 
             data = testdata))  |>   
  map(~ tab_model(.x))
```

However, instead of getting 3 tables (in sequence), I got a table with x as the variable name.

[image]

My question is, how can I generate 3 tables (in sequence) using `purrr::map()` and `tab_model()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, it would be a sound method to use 'as.formula' with col names.

```
sjtable_list <- testdata |> 
  select(sfa:pufa) |>
  names() %>% 
  map(~ lmer(as.formula(paste(.x, " ~ time_point + (1| subject)")), 
             data = testdata))  |>   
  map(~ tab_model(.x))

# get result
sjtable_list[[1]]
# or
names(sjtable_list) <- testdata |>  select(sfa:pufa) |>  names()
sjtable_list[["sfa"]]
```

If just print them in html, below code archive it.
But if you want more complex output..., excuse me I don' have good idea.

````
```{r}
sjtable_list <- testdata |> 
  select(sfa:pufa) |>
  names() %>% 
  map(~ lmer(as.formula(paste(.x, " ~ time_point + (1| subject)")), 
             data = testdata))  |>   
  map(~ tab_model(.x, title = "</br>"))  # title is just to make space.
```

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
a <- character()
for (i in 1:length(sjtable_list)){
  a <- paste(a, sjtable_list[[i]]$knitr)
}

knitr::raw_html(a)
```
````

Comment: It works if I do not use Rmarkdown. In Rmarkdown, your solution will generate three HTML files BUT outside the HTML generated document. What I am looking for are 3 tables arranged in sequence in HTML document (after I rendered the Rmd document)

Comment: @KIM Excuse me, I don't have elegant way. I added snippet just to print them in sequene.

Comment: I am grateful for your help, @cuttlefish. Let's wait if anyone can have the solution